# Programmatically created NSButtons won't press

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsview, nsbutton, nsbuttoncell

My programmatically created buttons essentially aren't being pushed when I click them. Any idea why? Nothing happens, the action doesn't fire, the image doesn't change to the alternate image, etc.

(I'm using a MomentaryChangeButton but I've set it to MomentaryPushIn (to check to see if it's pushing or not. It's not depressing.)

```
    NSButton *titleButton = [[NSButton alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(TITLE_BUTTON_X_OFFSET, TITLE_BUTTON_Y_OFFSET, TITLE_BUTTON_WIDTH, TITLE_BUTTON_HEIGHT)];
    [titleButton setBordered:NO];
    [titleButton setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    [titleButton setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:TITLE_BUTTON_NAME]];
    [titleButton setAlternateImage:[NSImage imageNamed:TITLE_BUTTON_PRESSED_NAME]];
    [titleButton setButtonType:NSMomentaryChangeButton];
    [self addSubview:titleButton];

    NSButton *aboutButton = [[NSButton alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(ABOUT_BUTTON_X_OFFSET, ABOUT_BUTTON_Y_OFFSET, ABOUT_BUTTON_WIDTH, ABOUT_BUTTON_HEIGHT)];
    [aboutButton setBordered:NO];
    [aboutButton setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    [aboutButton setButtonType:NSMomentaryChangeButton];
    [aboutButton setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:ABOUT_BUTTON_NAME]];
    [aboutButton setAlternateImage:[NSImage imageNamed:ABOUT_BUTTON_PRESSED_NAME]];
    [[aboutButton image] setSize:NSMakeSize(ABOUT_BUTTON_WIDTH, ABOUT_BUTTON_HEIGHT)];
    [[aboutButton alternateImage]setSize:NSMakeSize(ABOUT_BUTTON_WIDTH, ABOUT_BUTTON_HEIGHT)];
    [self addSubview:aboutButton];

    NSButton *settingsButton = [[NSButton alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(SETTINGS_BUTTON_X_OFFSET, SETTINGS_BUTTON_Y_OFFSET, SETTINGS_BUTTON_WIDTH, SETTINGS_BUTTON_HEIGHT)];
    [settingsButton setBordered:NO];
    [settingsButton setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    [settingsButton setButtonType:NSMomentaryChangeButton];
    [settingsButton setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:SETTINGS_BUTTON_NAME]];
    [settingsButton setAlternateImage:[NSImage imageNamed:SETTINGS_BUTTON_PRESSED_NAME]];
    [[settingsButton image] setSize:NSMakeSize(SETTINGS_BUTTON_WIDTH, SETTINGS_BUTTON_HEIGHT)];


    [self addSubview:settingsButton];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement `setTarget:` and `setAction:` for each of the buttons.

---

Full implement is :

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{

    NSString *SETTINGS_BUTTON_NAME=@"red.png";
    NSString *SETTINGS_BUTTON_PRESSED_NAME=@"green.png";

    NSButton *settingsButton = [[NSButton alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(20, 500, 120, 32)];
    [settingsButton setBordered:YES];
    [settingsButton setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    [settingsButton setButtonType:NSMomentaryChangeButton];
    [settingsButton setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:SETTINGS_BUTTON_NAME]];
    [settingsButton setAlternateImage:[NSImage imageNamed:SETTINGS_BUTTON_PRESSED_NAME]];
    [[settingsButton image] setSize:NSMakeSize(120,32)];

    [settingsButton setTitle:@"title"];
    [settingsButton setTarget: self];
    [settingsButton setAction: @selector(invisible:)]; //invisible is a selector see below
    [self.window.contentView addSubview: settingsButton];
}

- (IBAction)invisible:(id)sender{ //change this name accordingly
    NSLog(@"yepiiee");
}
```

EDIT: as per my convenient I did some changes as, image, and frame rect size, you can alter to your requirement.

Comment: Added these, it didn't do anything. Buttons still don't "press".

Comment: This is working, the button's color is getting changed from red to green.

Comment: This works when I add it to the window's content view. I'm trying to add it to a NSTableHeaderView, could that be why? All my original code seems to work in normal views but breaks the moment I add it to a NSTableHeaderView

Comment: TableHeaderView ???? nowhere you used to add button or buttonCell in headerView or headerCell?

Comment: Everything was showing up fine in the NSTableHeaderView so I figured I didn't need a NSTableHeaderCell...Apparently I do since no buttons work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check frame of the view to which you're adding buttons.
View can draw its subviews, but if buttons are not in "visible" frame area action won't receive.